# Azure Service Fabric: Using Reliable collections in ASP.NET Core Stateful Service directly

Tags: asp.net, azure-service-fabric

I built a Service Fabric Application with two services:

1. Stateful Data service that stores data in a reliable dictionary and exposes methods to add/remove/get data items from dictionary.
2. A stateless Web API service that acts a HTTP interface to outside world and that communicates using remoting to Data service to get data and display to user.

There is a provision to create stateful Web API service in Service Fabric. I tried to get rid of the data service and manage the reliable dictionary in the Web API service only. However, I am not able to access the **StateManager** in my controller. I am not able to find any samples online that do this.

Is my understanding correct about the stateful ASP.NET Core API services? That is, I can use reliable collections directly in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you can use reliable collections in an asp.net service. This sample is equal to what you are building: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-quickstart it contains an asp.net core stateful service.

Main things:

1. Your service has to derive from Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatefulService
2. In the serviceListener, you setup a ServiceReplicaListener (not ServiceInstanceListener)
3. In WebHostbuilder you add a singleton IRealibleStatemanager: .AddSingleton(this.StateManager))

Now your controllers will have access to the singleton StateManager:

```
 public MyDataController(IReliableStateManager stateManager)
    {
       this.stateManager = stateManager;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should also consider partitioning, if you need to scale.
In that case maybe a separate service is better.

(Not really an answer but I cannot comment since I am under 50 points:))

Comment: Your point is valid. One service will have multiple responsibilities, I guess I need to think about it too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the service to be available on all nodes allow listen on secondary replicas'.

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners(){
    return new ServiceReplicaListener[]{
        new ServiceReplicaListener(serviceContext =>
            new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) => {
                EventTracer.Current.LogSystemMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting http kestrel listner on {url}");
                return new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .ConfigureServices(
                         services => services
                         .AddSingleton<StatefulServiceContext>(serviceContext)
                         .AddSingleton<IReliableStateManager>(this.StateManager))
                     .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                     .UseStartup<Startup>()
                     .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                     .UseUrls(url)
                     .Build();
            }),"WebService",listenOnSecondary:true)

    };
}
```